# Comment/Post system in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship

I can't seem to get relationships concrete in my head with Laravel. Having tried to follow the docs for eloquent orm, I still can't get my foreign keys to *mean* something (I update them manually). Right now I am trying to get a bulletin board system to work. A user can create a bulletin post, and here it is working in my controller:

```
public function editPost($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->bulletin = new Bulletin;//new post
    $user->bulletin->creator_id = $id;//why doesn't it automatically update given the relationship?
    $user->bulletin->type = Input::get('type');
    $user->bulletin->title = Input::get('title');
    $user->bulletin->content = Input::get('bulletinEdit');
    $user->bulletin->save();

    if(Input::hasFile('bulletinImage')){
        $extension = Input::file('bulletinImage')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = str_random(9).'.'.$extension;

        $user->bulletin->photo = new Photo;
        $user->bulletin->photo->user_id = $id;
        $user->bulletin->photo->type = Input::get('type');
        $user->bulletin->photo->filename = $fileName;
        $user->bulletin->photo->touch();
        $user->bulletin->photo->save();

        Input::file('bulletinImage')->move('public/images/bulletin/',$fileName);
    }

    return Redirect::to('bulletin');
}
```

If I have the relationship set up properly, shouldn't the creator_id be updated automatically? Here is what I have in my models:

**Bulletin**

```
<?php

class Bulletin extends Eloquent {

public function creator()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment');
}

public function type()
{
    //if 1 then, etc
}

public function photos(){
    return $this->hasMany('Photo');
}
}
```

**User**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function tags()
    {   
        //TO REMOVE RECORD
        //User::find(1)->tags()->detach();

        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag'); 
    }

    public function createUser()
    {
        $password = Hash::make('secret');
    }

    public function bulletin()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Bulletin','creator_id');
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Profile');
    }
}
```

Could anybody give me some tips on tightening this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing it should work, you are just using more code and Eloquent has some methods to help you attach relationships, so I would try something like this:

```
public function editPost($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    // Create a new bulletin, passing the necesssary data

    $bulletin = new Bulletin(Input::only(['type', 'title', 'bulletinEdit']));

    // Attach the bulletin model to your user, Laravel should set the creator_id itself

    $bulletin = $user->bulletin()->save($bulletin);

    ...

    return Redirect::to('bulletin');
}
```

In your model, you'll have to:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

   protected $fillable = ['type', 'title', 'bulletinEdit'];

   ...
}
```

So Laravel doesn't give you a MassAssignmentException.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know. I am getting an error with the "new Bulletin" part, it is returning a mass assignment exception that just says "type", how do I set it up so that eloquent sends that input to the correct columns?

Comment: Sorry, edited to provide the fix for that error. And I just saw you have a different column `$user->bulletin->content = Input::get('bulletinEdit');`, so you may want to change it on your form or change the array you are passing to `create()`.